# How do I get the rank of the button

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

```
 <script>
    function showRank(){
      // I don't know what to do now 
    }
 <script>

 <section>
    <div data-index='1'>
        <p>First</p>
        <button  onclick='showRank()'>First</button>
    </div>
    <div data-index="2">
            <p>Second</p>
        <button onclick='showRank()'>Second</button>
    </div>
    <div data-index="3">
            <p>Third</p>
        <button onclick='showRank()'>Third</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

When I click any one of the buttons I want to console.log() the div in which the button is.
For example :

input -: `Clicked the button 'First'`

output -:

```
<div data-index='1'>
     <p>First</p>
     <button  onclick='showRank()'>First</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I easy way is passing the parameter to your function like this

```
<script>
    function showRank(varRank){
     console.log(varRank) 
    }
 <script>

 <section>
    <div data-index='1'>
        <p>First</p>
        <button  onclick='showRank("First")'>First</button>
    </div>
    <div data-index="2">
            <p>Second</p>
        <button onclick='showRank("Second")'>Second</button>
    </div>
    <div data-index="3">
            <p>Third</p>
        <button onclick='showRank("Third")'>Third</button>
    </div>
</section>
```